# pdfcrop not working with TeX Live 2016, LuaLaTeX

Tags: texlive, pdfcrop

I'm compiling

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \immediate\write18{pdfcrop PT1-matlab.pdf}
\end{document}
```

with

```
lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

on Windows but it fails silently and no PT1-matlab-crop.pdf is created.

```
pdfcrop PT1-matlab.pdf (./document.aux))
Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
```

It used to work with TeX Live 2015 and running

```
pdfcrop PT1-matlab.pdf
```

in the TeX Live command line results in a croppped PDF.

Comment: Load the package shellesc and read its documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Are you going to write an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the new luatex \write18 is no longer special. To get the functionality back: Load the package `shellesc` and read its documentation.